# How to remove special characters from slug that already exists in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My MongoDB Data looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0"
  },
  "title": "This is a title [Hello#$There1234] !!5678 @",
  "slug": "this--is-a-----title-[hello#$there1234]---!!5678-@----",
  "Post": "this is a post"
}
```

But I want it like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0"
  },
  "title": "This is a title [Hello#$There1234] !!5678 @",
  "slug": "this-is-a-title-hellothere1234-5678",
  "Post": "this is a post"
}
```

How to change slug for only `-` and alphabets and numbers, alphabet can be in any language.

Comment: So you want a slug composed only of letters, dashes (`-`), and with no trailing dash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way that might work by deconstructing the current `"slug"` into "allowable" characters and then `"$concat"` the chars back into a single string.  I have little regex-foo so I'm not sure this is the best `"regex"`, but it may be sufficient.  If your data is important, you should probably test this on some toy data first.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "slug": {
        "$rtrim": {
          "chars": "-",
          "input": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": {
                "$regexFindAll": {
                  "input": "$slug",
                  "regex": "[\\p{Xan}-]+"
                }
              },
              "initialValue": "",
              "in": {"$concat": ["$$value", "$$this.match"]}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{"multi": true}
)
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w3-5m9EiZ_l).

**UPDATE**

This is a bit ugly, and demonstrates my lack of regex-foo, but by adding another stage to execute a javascript `"$function"`, multiple `-` can be collapsed to just one.  Hopefully a regex master will see this and simplify the whole thing.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "slug": {
        "$rtrim": {
          "chars": "-",
          "input": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": {
                "$regexFindAll": {
                  "input": "$slug",
                  "regex": "[\\p{Xan}-]+"
                }
              },
              "initialValue": "",
              "in": {"$concat": ["$$value", "$$this.match"]}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "slug": {
        "$function": {
          "lang": "js",
          "args": ["$slug"],
          "body": "function(str) {return str.replace(RegExp('-+', 'g'), '-')}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dve5frhNuyB).

Comment: This is working fine but How to convert `--------` to just `-`

Comment: @Tribe56123 So, a single `-` is fine, but no consecutive repetitions of `-`, like `--`, or `---`, etc.? And no trailing `-`?

Comment: Yes, Just updated my question.

Comment: @Tribe56123 I added another stage in the pipeline to collapse multiple `-`.  Please see updated answer.